# What is the concise way of using gradle DirectoryProperty objects?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm upgrading from deprecated gradle properties, and instead of referencing the `File jar.destinationDir`, I'm using the `DirectoryProperty jar.destinationDirectory`

But because I need a java.nio.file.Path object, my code changes from
`jar.destinationDir.toPath()`
into
`jar.destinationDirectory.asFile.get().toPath()`

Is there some groovy way to omit at least the `.asFile.get()`?

Comment: Do you have a simple script that shows what you mean